# Filter array php with two conditions

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the bottom values of an array with two conditions as below :

1. Get all numeric values from the bottom until the next value is a string then stop the instruction, and leave all other values even if they are numeric
2. If the first values from the bottom are strings skip them and execute the first condition.

`<?php $data=[1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9]; ?>`

The output will be  7 8 9.

`<?php $data= [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web','web']; ?>`

`<?php $data= [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web']; ?>`

Both of conditions will have the same output: 7 8 9.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it works for the first condiotion :

`<?php
$data = [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9]; 
$newArray = array(); // resultant array
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if(is_int($value)){
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
    else{
        $newArray = array();    // reset if not integer
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
?>`

Comment: Please add the _I have tried_ code to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

**Logic:** Reverse the array and check weather the given element is integer, if it is an integer, put it into a temporary array, otherwise, check if the process of saving integer data has already been started, if yes, break the loop otherwise, continue with the loop. Finally, reverse the array again to get the data in same format.

```
<?php
$data= [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web'];
$process = false;
foreach(array_reverse($data) as $d){
    if(is_int($d)){
        $process = true;
        $temp[] = $d;
    }
    else if($process) break;
}
$result = array_reverse($temp);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: @ahmedhendah, if it worked for you, please upvote and green-tick the answer :)